# How to extend Codable functionality of Date and other built in types?

Tags: swift, extension-methods, decodable

I am trying to extend the functionality of `Date.init(from:Decoder)` to handle different formats passed from my server. Sometimes a date will be encoded as a string, sometimes that string nested in a dictionary. According to the Swift source, `Date` is decoded/encoded like:

```
extension Date : Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let timestamp = try container.decode(Double.self)
        self.init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timestamp)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    }
}
```

So I tried to extend that function as follows:

```
public extension Date {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let dateString: String
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) {
            dateString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .datetime)
        } else if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) {
            dateString = string
        } else {
            let timestamp = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self)
            self.init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timestamp)
            return
        }
        if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString) {
            self.init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        } else if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString, with: "yyyy-MM-dd") {
            self.init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Date format was unparseable.")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }
    }

}
```

However this function is never called. Then I tried to extend `KeyedDecodingContainer` to change `Date` decoding in the `decode(_:forKey)` as follows:

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    private enum TimeCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime
    }

    func decode(_ type: Date.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Date {
        let dateString: String
        if let timeContainer = try? self.nestedContainer(keyedBy: TimeCodingKeys.self, forKey: key) {
            dateString = try timeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .datetime)
        } else if let string = try? self.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            dateString = string
        } else {
            let value = try self.decode(Double.self, forKey: key)
            return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: value)
        }
        if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString) {
            return date
        } else if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString, with: Globals.standardDateFormat) {
            return date
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Date format was not parseable.")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }
    }

}
```

However, when this is called to decode a `Date` that I encoded by calling `container.encode(date, forKey: .date)`, I get a `typeMismatch` error that the data is not a `Double`. I am completely baffled as to what's going on, because the `encode(to:)` function for `Date` explicitly encodes a Double. I tried tracing my way through the `decode` calls in the Swift source code and it doesn't seem to ever call `Date.init(from:Decoder)`.

So I am wondering, is it possible to alter the way the `Date` type is decoded through this kind of extension? Is my only option to duplicate my custom `Date` decoding in every single model? What on earth calls `init(from:Decoder)`?

Comment: You can't override others' methods by providing your own versions in extensions. If you're using `JSONDecoder`, is there a reason you can't use its [`dateDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy)? If not, or you're trying to solve this for all `Encoder`s and `Decoder`s — the write solution is to write an adaptor type which wraps `Date` and offers its own `init(from:)` as you do above. You then wrap your `Date`s in the adaptor type before encoding/decoding.

Comment: I can't use the `dateDecodingStrategy` because I want a solution that works with all decoders and that can handle a nested date object passed from the API I'm using. I think you're right that I just need to make a subclass of `Date` instead of trying to add to the default `Date` behavior, the more I dig into it, the more it seems like mine wasn't the right approach.

Comment: Since `Date` is a `struct` and not a class, you can't subclass it — but you can introduce a new `struct` which has a `Date` value and encodes and decodes the date however you want. (This is what I meant by adaptor type above.)

Comment: Ugh, that's exactly what I wanted to avoid. My overall goal is to not have to duplicate the same date decoding in all my models, but I also don't want the fact that the dates are encoded stupid to cause the rest of my codebase to have to call `date.date` whenever I want to use a date. It really doesn't seem against the spirit of `Codable` and Swift's general philosophy of extending functionality to be able to change how `Date`s are decoded in general, but I guess Apple doesn't see it that way, or hasn't addressed this issue yet.

Comment: Er, overriding others' code in extensions is, I think, a pretty misleading feature of Swift. There's nothing special about `Codable` here — your extension works in your module, but when someone calls the method from another module (e.g., from within Foundation), they get the implementation they linked against, not yours. The right way to do it indeed requires some more boilerplate, but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this with the following code:

```
fileprivate struct DateWrapper: Decodable {
    var date: Date

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        date = try container.decode(Date.self)
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    private enum TimeCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime
    }

    func decode(_ type: Date.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Date {
        let dateString: String
        if let timeContainer = try? self.nestedContainer(keyedBy: TimeCodingKeys.self, forKey: key) {
            dateString = try timeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .datetime)
        } else if let string = try? self.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            dateString = string
        } else {
            return try self.decode(DateWrapper.self, forKey: key).date
        }
        if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString) {
            return date
        } else if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString, with: "yyyy-MM-dd") {
            return date
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Date format was not parseable.")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }
    }

}
```

The issue with trying to recreate the code of `Date.init(from:Decoder)` is that the type information is also encoded in the plist entry, so even though I knew the entry for the date was encoded as a `Double`, it would not let me extract a `Double` because that's not what the type tag says. I also could not call the default implementation of `decode(Date.self, forKey: key)` because that's the function I'm writing and this isn't a subclass so I can't call `super`. I tried a few clever things trying to extract the concrete `Decoder` from the `KeyedDecodingContainer` so I could call `Date.init(from:Decoder)` directly, but that didn't work because the context of the particular key was lost when I got the `Decoder` back. (See https://stablekernel.com/understanding-extending-swift-4-codable/ if you're curious about extracting `Decoder`s).

I knew I could achieve what I wanted by using a wrapper around `Date` to do the weird decoding, but I didn't want to have to append `.date` to all the places where I use dates in my codebase. Then I realized that for this default case that I was stuck on, the wrapper would allow me to extract the date from a `SingleValueDecodingContainer` instead of from a `KeyedDecodingContainer`, allowing me to call the default `Date` decoding code without ending up in an infinite loop calling my custom function.

This is probably super jank and inappropriate, but it works, and will save me a lot of boilerplate until I can get my API standardized.

EDIT: I rearranged this a bit to have better division of responsibilities and made it work with more container types

```
fileprivate struct DateWrapper: Decodable {

    var date: Date

    private enum TimeCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case datetime
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let dateString: String
        if let timeContainer = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: TimeCodingKeys.self) {
            dateString = try timeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .datetime)
        } else {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
                dateString = string
            } else {
                date = try container.decode(Date.self)
                return
            }
        }
        if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString) {
            self.date = date
        } else if let date = Utils.date(from: dateString, with: "yyyy-MM-dd") {
            self.date = date
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Date format was not parseable.")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
        }
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    func decode(_ type: Date.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> Date {
        return try self.decode(DateWrapper.self, forKey: key).date
    }

    func decode(_ type: [Date].Type, forKey key: K) throws -> [Date] {
        var container = try nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
        var dates: [Date] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            dates.append(try container.decode(Date.self))
        }
        return dates
    }

}

extension UnkeyedDecodingContainer {

    mutating func decode(_ type: Date.Type) throws -> Date {
        return try self.decode(DateWrapper.self).date
    }

}
```